# Flow of electrons by thermal excitation

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electrostatics

Consider the following thought experiment:

I have a copper wire which is attached to a voltmeter. Now I heat one half of the copper wire ( till temperature $T$)while I leave the other half at room temperature.

1. Would I be able to detect a tiny potential difference between the 2 ends or would I have to heat it uniformly to achieve a potential difference?
2. If this possible what should be the temperature $T$ ?

My reasoning is the following. Since one part of the wire is heated and not the other part, that part will be more thermally excited. This may cause some of the electrons to move which would get detected as a small current.

Correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: You appear to be looking at the [Seebeck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect)

Comment: @BySymmetry I don’t know about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you heat one end of a copper wire, there will be some redistribution of electrons, moving from the hot end to the cold end, which will represent a transient current.

If you maintain a constant temperature difference between the two ends of the wire, the new distribution of the electrons will stay unchanged: there will be a dynamic equilibrium between thermally induced diffusion of electrons and field induced drift.

This implies a non-zero potential difference and therefore a non-zero electrical field between the two ends of the wire, which should be detectable by a sensitive electric field meter.

If you try to measure the voltage between the hot and cold ends of the wire with a voltmeter, the outcome will depend on the material of the probes: if you use copper probes, you'll observe (at least, in theory) a short transient current, which would flow through the voltmeter. It would be of the same nature as the initial diffusion current in the copper wire and it will stop for the same reason, i.e., due to the dynamic equilibrium.

If, on the other hand, the probes are made from a different metal, we'll have a thermocouple, i.e., a heated junction between two dissimilar metals.

Given that other junctions in the loop, formed by the copper wire and the voltmeter with the probes, are kept at room temperature, some voltage will be induced in the loop (Seebeck effect) and that voltage would be measured by the voltmeter.

If you replace the voltmeter by an ammeter, you'll be able to measure the current in the loop caused by the induced potential difference.

Uniform heating would not produce any potential difference.

To summarize, there won't be any continuous current in the copper wire, but if another wire, made out of a dissimilar metal, is connected at the two ends of the original copper wire, a current will flow in the resulting loop.